# How was this maths educational video made?

Tags: technology-in-education, software, presentation

I would like to make math videos in the manner of [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVFWrMCfje8&list=PLCgncMh0TrCmrkvT7zW0x32flMJLuYMT5). The specific features which I like in this video are:

- the interactive freestyle drawing (see the beginning of the video)
- the way different colours are selected smoothly (00:28 into the video)
- the way pre-written text can appear (01:27)
- the way existing drawings can be replaced by written text smoothly  (05:37)
- the support for maths equations

I have tried Microsoft OneNote and Microsoft Powerpoint, which have been mentioned in similar questions here, but:

- I understand how to make pre-written text appear in Microsoft PowerPoint, but I cannot see how to allow freehand drawing, or the interactive nature of the presentation
- Conversely, Microsoft OneNote supports freehand drawing, but I am not sure about the text effects I mentioned.

Comment: My guess would be that this is a combination of some kind of presentation software (such as PowerPoint, or a pdf viewer and Beamer slides) and some kind of free-draw program on a tablet (such as Notability).  There is also the possibility that much of the text was added to the video in post-production.  You may also find [this question about technology for the classroom](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13571) relevant.

Comment: You can free hand draw in PowerPoint when it's in presentation mode.  I do it with a Bamboo pad/stylus.  To get into presentation mode, just type F5.  If there's a way to do smooth color changes, I don't know it.